# Монитор удаленных хостов на flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Нужно к flask прикрутить монитор хостов. Когда пользователь заходит на страницу, он 
должен видеть:

```
 192.168.0.1 - в сети
 192.168.0.2 - не в сети
 192.168.0.3 - в сети
```

Допустим, проверятся будет по 22 порту

```
import socket
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 try:
     s.connect(('192.168.0.1', 22))
     print("Хост в сети")
 except socket.error as e:
     print("Хост не в сети")
 s.close()
```

Желательно, чтоб динамически обновлялось Подскажите, как реализовать.

Comment: Сначала реализуете на питоне проверку работы. Попробуйте подключаться сокетом к указанному адресу и если ошибок нет -- значит "в сети"

Comment: Вот вам хороший гайд, че и как сделать: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200159/a-website-status-monitor-in-python-flask на codereview. Это поможет.

Comment: @ 1st Sentinel 31 Year Perl Hist - Спасибо!